# What limits are put on mission profiles by maximum tolerated G-force?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, medical, rail-gun

NASA standards https://standards.nasa.gov/documents/viewdoc/3315785/3315785 includes this graph of maximum allowable G-force and duration:

[image]

With some creative license, this curve could be extrapolated to:

[image]

Science fiction concepts for high-G space exploration (rail guns, nuclear rockets) are limited by the envelope of this time-G force curve. It is all very well to propose Lunar surface launches or short duration, high acceleration travel within the solar system. But it would be interesting to know the limits imposed by high-G tolerance of the crew.

Some carefully applied calculus should be able to integrate under the blue curve to give the limits of speed and distance attainable in a G-force limited mission.

Using this data and assumptions,

1. What is the minimum length of rail gun needed to launch humans to Lunar escape velocity?
2. What is the minimum transit time from Earth to Europa orbital insertion?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Moon escape velocity is 2380 m/s.

For a constant acceleration, the needed distance and time are:

```
4.0 g : 72176 m and 60.65 s
4.5 g : 64156 m and 53.91 s
5.0 g : 57741 m and 48.52 s
6.0 g : 48117 m and 40.43 s
7.5 g : 38494 m and 32.34 s
10. g : 28870 m and 24.26 s
```

So the needed rail gun is too long anyway. Non constant acceleration according to the blue line was not considered.

Comment: All your scenarios are within NASAs G-force/time limits for launch, so rail launch to Lunar escape velocity is not prohibited by human G-force tolerance. The rails are long by runway standards, but not by high speed railroad standards.

Comment: There is much more speed needed than high speed railroad standards. About 500 km/h or 138 m/s are not much when we need when we 8568 km/h or 2380 m/s. More than 17 times faster.